# Permutations and combinations

Tags: permutations, combinations

An elected staff member wants to take five members of his staff to an undisclosed secure location. How many members must the elected official employ in order to have a minimum of 20 different groups from which to choose?

Choices:

$ A.$ $7$

$ B.$ $8$

$ C.$ $9$

$ D.$ $10$

$ E.$ $11$

Comment: How can I set up a formula?

Comment: 5 minutes of his staff?

Comment: Question needs to be a little more clear..

Comment: Are they going fishing for red herrings in that undisclosed secure location?

Comment: Does the question mean "what is the least number of members necessary to have at least 20 different groups?" I can only assume this to be the intended question.

Comment: Will R, I also think that is what the question is trying to say.

Comment: @user268238 If there are $x$ people, how many ways are there to choose a group of 5 members?

Comment: There are x!/[5!(x-5)!] people (assuming order does not matter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose he has $x$ people to choose from. Then we know that he can make $x(x - 1)(x - 2)(x - 3)(x - 4) / 5!$ groups, since permutation does not matter.

In other words, he can pick one person first, and he will have $x-1$ people left to choose from for the next person. He does this $5$ times, hence the formula.

You may have seen it written as $ \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

So the question is when is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
{1 \over 5!} \cdot x(x - 1)(x - 2)(x - 3)(x - 4) & \geq & 20\\
x(x - 1)(x - 2)(x - 3)(x - 4) & \geq & 5! \cdot 20\\
x(x - 1)(x - 2)(x - 3)(x - 4) & \geq & 2400
\end{eqnarray*}
And since $x$ is an natural number, i.e., $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...\}$ you can just try answers until you hit it.

Comment: This is none of my answer choices. 2400 is way off.

Comment: Try plugging $x=\text{one of your choices}$ into the polynomial shown and see if the answer is bigger than $2400$.

Comment: All of the x vales in my choices work, and the smallest one is x=7. So the answer choice is A

Comment: @user268238 pefect, and for completeness, show that 6 is too small, and you are done